# Using Group by and select all in a SQL Query

Tags: postgresql

I have **employee_data** table with following fields,

- id - Integer (Auto Increment)
- first_name - text
- last_name -text

And I have **title table** with following fields,

- id - Integer (Auto Increment)
- title_name - text

And I have **employee_title** table with following fields,

- id - Integer (Auto Increment)
- title_id - integer (id of title table -fkey)
- period_to - date

I want to get the max `period_to` with all 3 table data according to each employee by joining the 3 tables.
But i cannot retrieve all data because of a error showing.
error : `column "jt.code" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

### my sql

```
SELECT ed.*, max(et.period_to) FROM employee_data ed 
JOIN employee_title et ON et.employee_id=ed.id 
JOIN title jt ON jt.id=et.title_id
WHERE et.deleted = 0 
GROUP BY ed.id;
```

I want to select all data. Please help me on this.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images. (And also take a look at [mcve].)

Comment: "_a error showing_" - which error?

Answer (score 1):

Often the PostgreSQL extension `DISTINCT ON()` is the simplest and fastest way to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ed.id) *
FROM employee_data ed 
   JOIN employee_title et ON et.employee_id=ed.id 
   JOIN title jt ON jt.id=et.title_id
WHERE et.deleted = 0
ORDER BY ed.id, et.period_to DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below - add ed.first_name,ed.last_name in group by

```
SELECT ed.id,ed.first_name,ed.last_name,title_name, max(et.period_to) FROM employee_data ed 
JOIN employee_title et ON et.employee_id=ed.id 
JOIN title jt ON jt.id=et.title_id
WHERE et.deleted = 0 
GROUP BY ed.id,ed.first_name,ed.last_name,title_name
```

Comment: i want to get all data of `employee_title ` and  `title ` tables too.